# How to avoid convoluted logic for custom log messages in code?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I know the title is a little too broad, but I'd like to know how to avoid (if possible) this piece of code I've just coded on a solution of ours.

The problem started when this code resulted in not enough log information:

```
...
var users = [someRemotingProxy].GetUsers([someCriteria]);
try
{
    var user = users.Single();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    logger.WarnFormat("Either there are no users corresponding to the search or there are multiple users matching the same criteria.");
    return;
}
...
```

We have a business logic in a module of ours that needs there to be a single 'User' that matches some criteria. It turned out that, when problems started showing up, this little 'inconclusive' information was not enough for us to properly know what happened, so I coded this method:

```
private User GetMappedUser([searchCriteria])
{
    var users = [remotingProxy]
           .GetUsers([searchCriteria])
           .ToList();

    switch (users.Count())
    {
        case 0:
            log.Warn("No user exists with [searchCriteria]");
            return null;

        case 1:
            return users.Single();

        default:
            log.WarnFormat("{0} users [{1}] have been found"
                          users.Count(), 
                          String.Join(", ", users);
            return null;
    }
```

And then called it from the main code like this:

```
...
var user = GetMappedUser([searchCriteria]);
if (user == null) return;
...
```

The first odd thing I see there is the `switch` statement over the `.Count()` on the list. This seems very strange at first, but somehow ended up being the cleaner solution. I tried to avoid exceptions here because these conditions are quite normal, and I've heard that it is bad to try and use exceptions to control program flow instead of reporting actual errors. The code was throwing the `InvalidOperationException` from Single before, so this was more of a refactor on that end.

Is there another approach to this seemingly simple problem? It seems to be kind of a [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation, with the logs in between the code and all that, but I fail to see a decent or elegant way out of it. It's even worse in our case because the same steps are repeated twice, once for the 'User' and then for the 'Device', like this:

1. Get unique user
2. Get unique device of unique user

For both operations, it is important to us to know exactly what happened, what users/devices were returned in case it was not unique, things like that.

Comment: That's why AOP was invented.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you would achieve a cleaner code using AOP in this case? I'm aware at how PostSharp or interception mechanisms work, but I fail to see how they would be applied for this instance, since this is not a "before<method>" or "after<method>" situation.

Answer (score 1):

@AntP hit upon the answer I like best.  I think the reason you are struggling is that you actually have two problems here.  The first is that the code seems to have too much responsibility.  Apply this simple test: give this method a simple name that describes everything it does.  If your name includes the word "and", it's doing too much.  When I apply that test, I might name it "GetUsersByCriteriaAndValidateOnlyOneUserMatches()."  So it is doing two things.  Split it up into a lookup function that doesn't care how many users are returned, and a separate function that evaluates your business rule regarding "I can handle only one user returned".

You still have your original problem, though, and that is the switch statement seems awkward here. The strategy pattern comes to mind when looking at a switch statement, although pragmatically I'd consider it overkill in this case.

If you want to explore it, though, think about creating a base "UserSearchResponseHandler" class, and three sub classes:  NoUsersReturned; MultipleUsersReturned; and OneUserReturned.  It would have a factory method that would accept a list of Users and return a UserSearchResponseHandler based on the count of users (encapsulating the logic of the switch inside the factory.)  Each handler method would do the right thing: log something appropriate then return null, or return a single user.

The main advantage of the Strategy pattern comes when you have multiple needs for the data it identifies.  If you had switch statements buried all over your code that all depended on the count of users found by a search, then it would be very appropriate.  The factory can also encapsulate substantially more complex rules, such as "user.count must = 1 AND the user[0].level must = 42 AND it must be a Tuesday in September".  You can also get really fancy with a factory and use a registry, allowing for dynamic changes to the logic.  Finally, the factory nicely separates the "interpreting" of the business rule from the "handling" of the rule.

But in your case, probably not so much. I'm guessing you likely have only the one occurrence of this rule, it seems pretty static, and it's already appropriately located near the point where you acquired the information it's validating.  While I'd still recommend splitting out the search from the response parser, I'd probably just use the switch.

A different way to consider it would be with some Goldilocks tests.  If it's truly an error condition, you could even throw:

```
if (users.count() < 1)
{
    throw TooFewUsersReturnedError;
}

if (users.count() > 1)
{
    throw TooManyUsersReturnedError;
}

return users[0];  // just right
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I'm a bit stumped with this one because it was rather simple before, as it basically boiled down to a `.Single()` call. It was when I had to add meaningful error messages that the clumsiness started. I really wonder if it would really be possible to implement this more clearly, perhaps by using some form of AOP as was suggested in a comment. I also thought about using a validation method that threw specific exceptions containing the messages but, again, these conditions really aren't errors per se, but normal and valid code paths.

Comment: @julealgon, I would add that if you can ever validly get multiple users back from search, then you would have a second condition where the polymorphic MultipleUsersReturned could handle the case, and suddenly Strategy sounds like a winning pattern. If you never have a valid case of more than one user returned, why would you return a list container of users?

Comment: this method is very general in our API, but is being used in a context that requires uniqueness of both the users and devices. The rest of the system does not have this restriction. It's basically an specialization of our product to a client that enforces these rules. The rules themselves are not present in the base product. Perhaps the better approach here would be to construct another business layer specific to each client, validating these kinds of rules there. Then again, I'm already doing exactly that here. This is nontrivial at the moment though unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
public class UserResult
{
    public string Warning { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Result { get; set; }
}

public UserResult GetMappedUsers(/* params */) { }

public void Whatever()
{
    var users = GetMappedUsers(/* params */);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(users.Warning))
        log.Warn(users.Warning);
}
```

Switch for a `List<string> Warnings` if required. This treats your `GetMappedUsers` method more like a service that returns some data and some metadata about the result, which allows you to delegate your logging to the caller - where it belongs - so your data access code can get on with just doing its job.

Although, to be honest, in this scenario I would prefer simply to return a list of user IDs from `GetMappedUsers` and then use `users.Count` to evaluate your "cases" in the caller and log as appropriate.

Comment: I think I don't understand your proposition here, because you are still returning a list of users inside the model, and I want the unique one after the call since I have to do operations on it (in case there really was a unique user) or end the operation otherwise.